# How to upload picture using Ajax in Django ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to upload profile picture using Ajax (using FormData) in Django.

Following is the code I used it in html page,

```
<img src="/media/{{user_profile.picture}}" width="150" height="150" alt="" id="pro_file"/>
<input id="upload-file" type="file" name="file"/>
```

and in jQuery (Ajax),

```
var fd = new FormData();
var vidFileLength = $('#upload-file')[0].files.length;
if(vidFileLength === 0){
    var files = $('#pro_file').attr('src');
}
else{
    var files = $('#upload-file')[0].files[0];
}
fd.append('file',files);
```

Then I have sent the `fd` in data attribute in Ajax.

However, in views.py following is my snippet code,

```
fd = request.FILES
try:
    profile_pic = fd['file']
except KeyError as e:
    profile_pic = request.POST['file']
profile_pic = str(profile_pic).replace("/media/","")
```

Using this method, my code works but I doubt is it a proper way to do it ? Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user already has a picture and they don't choose a new image via the input, is there a reason to send the URL back to the server? The server could look it up from the database if it really needs it. And if this is an update profile view, then you don't need to do anything and can ignore it not being sent back.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reverting back. It's a update profile page, and using FormData, I am sending profile picture along with other information using .append() method. But if for the next time, I don't want to update profile picture but just the text in the profile then I get this error `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file'` Is there any way I can make it work even if the `fd['file']` is Null.

Comment: You should check if the key exists in `request.FILES` before accessing it via `if 'file' in request.FILES` or you can use `.get()` which will default to `None` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Done. I want to confirm is it a safe way to do it ? Or can you provide me some of your worthy suggestions to improve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe way to do it"?